# Create Table Spring JDBC from key

Tags: java, json, database

> So i'm trying to create table in database by using key from JSON Object, but it showing error like this

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE TABLE siswas (  Category INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  nama VARCHAR(45) ,  Absensi VARCHAR(45) ,  Entertain LONG ,  id INT ,  Gaji_Pokok INT ,  Tunjangan_Pulsa LONG ,  Tunjangan_Makan LONG ,  Tunjangan_Trans LONG ,  Tunjangan_Ent LONG ,  PRIMARY KEY (id));]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key] with root cause
```

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

> Here is Mycode

```
public void buatTable(ArrayList<String> array) {
    System.out.println("Creating table at database");
    id = array.get(0);
    nama = array.get(1);
    Category = array.get(2);
    Gaji_pokok = array.get(3);
    Absensi = array.get(4);
    Entertain = array.get(5);
    TunjanganP = array.get(6);
    TunjanganM = array.get(7);
    TunjanganT = array.get(8);
    TunjanganE = array.get(9);

    jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS Karyawan");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE Karyawan (" +
            "  "+id+" INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "  "+nama+" VARCHAR(45) ," +
            "  "+Category+" VARCHAR(45) ," +
            "  "+Gaji_pokok+" LONG ," +
            "  "+Absensi+" INT ," +
            "  "+Entertain+" INT ," +
            "  "+TunjanganP+" LONG ," +
            "  "+TunjanganM+" LONG ," +
            "  "+TunjanganT+" LONG ," +
            "  "+TunjanganE+" LONG ," +
            "  PRIMARY KEY (id));");
}
```

is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify which database you are using, but try to change LONG to INT